# Google drive webhook check row inserted

Tags: php, push-notification, google-drive-api, webhooks

i am using google drive push notification to track new rows enter into the google sheet.once the new row arrived i save the row information in database.when i read the push notification doc i understand i can track changes for `Files resources` & `Changes resources` .but the push notification trigger immediatly when a change occure. so i cannot guarantee a row is finished typing.how should i know if a row is completed? is there any event for that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the row being entered cell by cell or inserted all at once? Do you know how many columns a row is supposed to have?

Comment: inserted cell by cell.

Comment: Do you know how many columns a row is supposed to have? yes via api

Comment: If you use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), you could implement an `onEdit` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that would fire on each cell edit and is able to retrieve the edited cell. You could set-up your script in such a way, that you push notifaction function is called only if the edited cell is in the column of your choice (the last of a row).

Comment: Thank you.can I inject this app script for the existing project app .so that project app can access changes in sheets of users connected the app(via google oauth)

Comment: You can use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) to incorporate the Apps Script into your project. Might be a bit tricky, but eventually you can set up the Apps Script in such a way that it returns a value if an edit in the column of interest is made, and then you can evaluate this return value with the [execution response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/ExecutionResponse).
, but you need to find a way to connect you

Comment: https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/07/05/linking-cloud-platform-project-to-google-apps-script-project/ could this help me??

Comment: Yes, see also [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)

Comment: sadly api cannot create trigger see here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#limitations am i correct?

Comment: is this possible anyhow? i have read app script api tutorial

Comment: You are right about triggers, but maybe you can create your script with trigger from the Apps Script editor interface and then only call instead of creating with the Apps Script API.

Comment: Nope.users is authenticated via oauth.so I need to use app script API right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207331/discussion-between-ziganotschka-and-soju).